# Feature Request: Starring system that isn't easily abused

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

The whole point of starring in chat was to mark either statements you liked or something good or amusing that also held a significant importance. Lately I have noticed that multiple users, currently unknown, star either statements that have no need to be starred, or blocks of statements.

Example would be in [Star Lobby of AskUbuntu Chat Room.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room/?tab=stars) where
[Another star for just nonsense! Who is doing that????](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19847713#19847713)  gets starred. It does seem trivial to some, but to most of us it removes the point of having it in the first place.

There are two other feature request and discussions seen [here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5298/askubuntu-chat-starring-mechanism) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132873/chat-stars-on-trivial-messages).

I would like to add that in both cases it seems that simply telling mods to do their job doesn't help the situation. A mechanic to chat ban for starring things so often. Use too many in a day, get banned for additional day. However, how the number comes into should be be heavily discussed.

Comment: Another suggestion could be to "pay" for a star with 1 rep...

Comment: So... you're saying that we shouldn't star a dozen messages a dozen times each congratulating me on something?

Comment: unless everytime is so importance we must drop everything, then no, no you shouldn't.

Comment: If this ever gets implemented I might as well stop chatting. What's the point ...

Comment: Considering what is "star worthy" currently varies by the room, I don't see a point in interfering with communities. If they think something is very important and should be read, it can be pinned.

Comment: What would you say that the point of having stars in the first place **is**? You're just saying that it removes the point for you, but what *is* the point according to you?

Comment: To show there is a point of over doing it.  And to by example not get stupid with it.

Comment: You have 20 stars per day.  According to economics, you should spend all 20 stars so you get the most value possible per day.  I don't spend all 20 stars each day, bu I have no problem with someone who does.

Comment: @Virusboy that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Really, with this many downvotes, that is not going to be approved any time soon

Comment: Its not going to be closed anytime soon.

Comment: I disagree with almost all of this, but one small improvement we could make would be to add a short time delay between starring (maybe 30 seconds or so) to prevent users from spamming the star queue by just going up the page, starring everything. People does this every so often in my site's chat room and the users there do not like it.

Comment: Sssssso nice. When someone complains for rage unmotivated downvotes, general reply is something along the lines of "stop crying for fake internet points, users are entitled to vote like they want and they are free to vote someone based on the position of clouds in the sky"... but apply that to starboard and rage ensures. Mind if I join you as you enjoy the show, Discord? I have bought pop-corn....

Answer (score 12):

> A mechanic to chat ban for starring things so often. Use too many in a day, get banned for additional day.

There is already a limit for starring things. You can use up to 20 stars per day, per room. There is no ban though, thankfully. Banning people for starring things seems quite a bit overkill to me.

The discussion about stars came up recently during Winterbash when there was [a hat for starring things in chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245300/213556)

I will post some things from my answer to that question.

First of all, **There is no way of preventing people from starring messages.** Everyone stars things as they like. The star system gives priority to messages with more stars, so that they remain visible on the right-hand side bar for a longer time.

The usefulness of stars still remain, even if others star some things you don't approve of. You can always find a list of [messages you have starred](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room/?tab=stars&filter=mystars) and when you search for messages, you can easily sort them by the number of stars.

Answer (score 10):

I vehemently disagree with this request.

Who decides when something is nonsense? And why should we discourage it? I'm mindful of a quote from the legendary Gene Wilder in *Willy Wonka & the Chocolate Factory*, "A little nonsense now and then is relished by the wisest men."

There are real, serious issues on SE/SO - people trying to game the system for personal gain, people just generally being obnoxious putzes, questions and answers that need a little TLC. Let's focus on real issues that actually matter.

Comment: Right because it doesnt annoy any mods or anything.. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Virusboy How exactly do people using stars annoy the mods?? Honestly, I'm curious about your stance on that.

Comment: I said abusing not using.

Comment: @Virusboy Annoying mods and users and being an important issue to solve are two different things.

Comment: Tell me @Virusboy, how do you know it's annoying a mod? Do you have a confirmation from a mod saying "Hey Virusboy, all these dang starred posts in chat are annoying me; please make a meta post ASAP plz!!!!".  You aren't a mod yourself, obviously, so I don't understand why you're projecting and assuming it annoys mods