# Is there a query that returns answers one vote away from the Pizza hat?

Tags: support, data-explorer, winter-bash-2018

I want to identify answers that are just one vote away from the Pizza Hat (was Extra Toppings last year). Searching for "pizza" or "toppings" on [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) did not reveal a suitable query.

How to query for that trigger?

Comment: What is the trigger? Worth noting that SEDE only updates once a week so even if you have query it is rather useless. And are you interested in candidates that will earn you that hat or for others? The goal of why you need that query is unclear.

Comment: The trigger is getting the third upvote for an answer to a question that has already an accepted answer. I don't mind getting somewhat obsolete data; before any reaction I will examine question and answer manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/947351/pizza-time) might do the trick. The problem is that vote data (including accept votes) is rounded off (only dates are stored, not time), so it might select too many answers.

```sql
SELECT pa.Id AS [Post Link]
  FROM Posts AS q
  INNER JOIN Posts AS aa
    ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = aa.Id
  INNER JOIN Votes AS v
    ON v.PostId = aa.Id
   AND v.VoteTypeID = 1
  INNER JOIN Posts AS pa
    ON pa.ParentId = q.Id
   AND pa.CreationDate > v.CreationDate -- posted after an answer has been accepted
   AND pa.Id != aa.Id
   AND pa.CreationDate >= '2018-12-12' -- Winter Bash start
   AND pa.Score = 2 -- one vote away from being awarded the Pizza hat
```

Of course, this kind of data is stale rather quickly. SEDE has just updated this morning, but given the young age of all answers, it's bound to be outdated in the next days.